# Android: Get Bluetooth RSSI value from specific BluetoothDevice

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, rssi

I'm making an Android application in which I need to be able to know the RSSI value of a specific device continuously. I have no problem getting the RSSI while scanning for devices however this is too slow for what I need.

I was thinking it might be possible to get the RSSI of a specific instance of a BluetoothDevice but I really have no idea where to start, so I'm asking here.

Is this possible? And if it is, do you know how to do it?

Or if you know another way to get the proximity value from another specific devices then please tell me! :)

Thanks!!

Comment: You can only obtain an RSSI value when you receive something from the device.  What sort of operations are happening with it?  Are you connected?  Is it simply sending undirected advertisements?  Is this conventional bluetooth, or bluetooth low energy?

Comment: @ChrisStratton For the moment I'm obtaining the RSSI while scanning for bluetooth devices. I could connect to the device if it's necessary, in fact I've tried but I couldn't figure out how to get the RSSI while connected. I'm using conventional bluetooth :)

Comment: @tupini07 have you figured it out? I am running into the same thing exactly

Comment: No @Snake .. I am sorry but I haven't found any solution to this problem, to my knowledge the only way of getting the RSSI value is during device discovery :/ .. I hope this question gets an answer soon. If I find any solution I'll let you know :)

Comment: Thanks man. unfortunetly this is the only way I found too

Answer (score 1):

If your use case allows you to connect to a device then it should be possible to get RSSI at a higher frequency than scanning. Once you connect to a device and get a `BluetoothGatt` object you can call `BluetoothGatt#readRemoteRssi()`. This results in a callback to `BluetoothGattCallback#onReadRemoteRssi()`.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but how is it exactly that I get the `BluetoothGatt` object?

Comment: `BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange()` provides an instance.

Comment: I tried what you say but I found out I need it to be conventional bluetooth and not low energy.. but thanks anyway :)